# Read lines from file as is in Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a text file which contains one string per line, and every string is already formated for Java, meaning that everything is escaped already. I tried to use BufferedReader, but it escapes every backslash in the string, making the string not to look as it should (ex. "\"hello\"" would turn out as "\\"hello\\"). Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: You don't need to escape things to read them. Everything is read verbatim.

Comment: Go read what a `String` literal is.

Comment: but there are also unprintable characters in the strings that need to be escaped

Comment: Then you'll have to do processing on the read `String`. As the answer below states, the content of the file will be interpreted literally.

Comment: If you mean that you want a newline character `\n`, to appear, literally, as `\n` rather than your text being split, then you have to find the character `\n` (not the string) in your read string and replace it with the two characters ``\`` and `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the content of the file itself.  That's only for when you're typing a String literal in Java code.  When it's read directly from a file, the content of the file will be interpreted literally.

In other words, if your file says:

```
"hi"
```

Reading that into a String and then `System.out.println`ing it will print out

```
"hi"
```

If you have a problem with unprintable characters, this might have to do with an encoding issue (you'll have to be more specific and give an example).  I always find this article enlightening: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

To read a file in with a certain encoding, use an [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) to set the encoding.

But it looks like you're reading in source and a part of it has a String you want to interpret.  For that particular String, you can pass it into [StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: the file is from a java source, and there are some characters that cannot be printed, but are needed, represented as backslash and octalcode

Answer (score 0):

You can try [beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/embeddedmode.html)

for example, let´s suppose you have a file like this

> \"xyz\"

then

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import bsh.Interpreter;


public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Interpreter i = new Interpreter();  // Construct an interpreter

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ReadFile.class.getResourceAsStream("file.txt")));
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
//          System.out.println(line);
            i.eval("foo = \""+line+"\"");
            String foo = (String)i.get("foo");
            System.out.println(foo);
        }
        br.close();

    }

}
```

you'll get

> "xyz"

(and not \"xyz\")

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use BufferedReader, but it escapes every backslash in the string, making the string not to look as it should (ex. "\"hello\"" would turn out as "\"hello\").

No it doesn't. You are mistaken.